# C# combobox, assign text value to variable on focus lost event?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox with customer ID's loaded.  I have a function that executes some queries when a combobox item is selected however the current functionality dose not do anything if a user types in a vale.  I am trying to use a on focus lost event for the combobox to achive this functionality however my current attempts are returning a null value when focus is lost.

I am adding a event handler as

```
cbxCustID.LostFocus += new EventHandler(cbxCustID_LostFocus);
```

The function is as follows

```
private void cbxCustID_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentText = cbxCustID.SelectedValue.ToString();  //  <-- error on this line
    loadName(currentText);
    loadDGV(currentText);
}
```

Even when a combobox item has been selected loosing focus on the combobox produces the following error.  "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

If anyone has any advice or is able to provide a nudge in the right direection it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Text` property:

```
private void cbxCustID_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentText = cbxCustID.Text;  
    loadName(currentText);
    loadDGV(currentText);
}
```

Comment: I could have swore I allready tried that.  Apparently not lol

Answer (score 1):

You'll get that error if `SelectedValue` is `null` and you try to call the `ToString` method on it.

You can use the `?.` [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to return `null` early and avoid the exception:

```
string currentText = cbxCustID.SelectedValue?.ToString();
```

Now, depending on your needs, you may still need to check if `currentText` is `null` after this assignment, before calling the other methods:

```
private void cbxCustID_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentText = cbxCustID.SelectedValue?.ToString();

    if (currentText != null)
    {
        loadName(currentText);
        loadDGV(currentText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used code pope's answer but I did use some of your example in my error handeling.